# How to add replicate fields when adding content?

Tags: entities

I've got a drupal structure that I'm trying to set up for hospitality venues so it has information like opening hours, and what is going on at those times. E.g. At Joe's Burgers between 9-5 Monday-Thursday it is a restaurant, but from 9-5 Friday-Saturday it's a nightclub.

I've got fields of venue name, opening hours, and category (e.g. bar, nightclub, restaurant, etc), and therefore am able to add content for one time frame: e.g. Joe's Burgers is a restaurant from 9-5 Monday-Thursday. But I don't know how to set it up so that I can attach further details such as it's a nightclub 9-5 Friday-Saturday.

Is there a button I can add into the 'add content' section which allows me to replicate the opening hours and category fields so that I can have multiple opening hours and category combinations under one venue name?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) to set up a field that contains both a category and a date as one unit.

Then all you would need to do is set the field collection to allow multiple values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to replicate an existing time collection, or do you just need to add more?

If you just need more, [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) will let you add multiple collections of fields. Each collection can have the fields you need: name, hours, category, etc